# /etc/fedora-release shows wrong release

Tags: fedora

I'm running Fedora 14 and cat `/etc/fedora-release` shows `redhat release 5`. Besides manually modifying the file, is there a proper way of fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `yum reinstall fedora-release` as root.

As an aside, you might want to investigate how that got installed that way.  There might be other problems on your system.